# Cover art of Karma to Burn's Almost Heathen

Tags: rock, artwork, alternative-rock

Please have a look at the cover art of [Karma to Burn's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma_to_Burn) album Almost Heathen:

[image]

There is a second version of it, with some subtle changes:

[image]

In the background, you can see three men standing together, each holding his right hand up, with the number 1291 displayed below them. To the right, an old man is sitting there, with the number 2001 (the album's release year) displayed below.

When I saw this, it reminded me of [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Charter_of_1291) related [things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCtlischwur) most Swiss people would be reminded of. Then I saw that the old man to the left is holding a Swiss flag in the second version of the cover art, where you can also read the names of the cantons of Genève and Neuchâtel at the bottom.

Is there a specific meaning to the cover art? Has the band any connection to Switzerland or Swiss myths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the source of the cover art and its connection to Switzerland. It's a painting by Albert Gantner from 1910, the year when the production and sale of [Absinthe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absinthe) was prohibited. I found the painting on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absinthe#Switzerland) page about Absinthe, in the section where the probihibition in Switzerland is mentioned.

The dead woman in the painting is the *fée verte*, the green fairy, a common name for Absinthe:

[image]

Comment: Interesting stuff. What kind of band is Karma to Burn and why would they be interested in the absinthe prohibition (which by the way was not only prohibited in the Switzerland but also in France and perhaps other countries too due to it's poisonous properties)?

Comment: @joseem It's a Stoner Metal band. Most likely they just liked the art, and perhaps they also like to drink Absinthe :-)

Comment: Yes, the art is quite neat. And you can drink (properly manufactured)absinthe quite safely nowadays :-)